# React + Vite App not loading at first launch after pushing a Client Update

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a React application bundled with Vite, and it generally works well. However, I've encountered a recurring issue every time I push an update to the site. On the first visit after the update, the web app fails to load correctly, and I receive the following error message in the console:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

To resolve this issue, I have to refresh the page. After the refresh, everything works as expected until the next update is pushed.

I believe the problem stems from the main JavaScript file of React:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/index-b9f535df.js"></script>
```

The error seems to be caused by the app looking for a JavaScript file that doesn't exist anymore due to the update. Indeed, after refreshing, the correct file appears to be different, as shown here:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/index-5812cc8c.js"></script>
```

Notably, the file name of the main index changes with every update. I'm trying to understand why this error occurs and how to prevent it. Is there a way to make the app recognize the updated JavaScript file without needing a manual page refresh from the user?

Thank you so much.